# How to detect a collision of two images in lua? (without physics)

Tags: lua

I have one image drag droped and other images. I want to increment a counter when two images 'touch' each other. How to implement this?
I'm begginer in coding so I have no idea on how do that.

Comment: What programming environment you are using?  Please set corresponding tag (such as "corona") under your question so that people which help you are after could easily find your question.

Comment: In case you aren't sure what @EgorSkriptunoff means, he's basically asking this: what are you making? A website? A game? An application? If you're making a game, what engine are you using? Corona? LOVE2D? Please give us as much information about your unique circumstances as possible; we can't quite help you until we know things like how information about the images is stored, how the passage of time is represented. etc. Please don't be afraid to let me know if you aren't quite sure what I mean.